# Having trouble making sense of the df command

Tags: centos, filesystems, partition, disk-usage, udev

```
uname -a
Linux CentOS01.localdomain 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 15 15:05:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the output of lsblk on the centos VM I'm playing with:

```
lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   30G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0 29.5G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0 27.5G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb               8:16   0    1G  0 disk
├─sdb1            8:17   0  200M  0 part
├─sdb2            8:18   0  200M  0 part
├─sdb3            8:19   0    1K  0 part
└─sdb4            8:20   0  523M  0 part
sdc               8:32   0  1.2G  0 disk
sr0              11:0    1 60.8M  0 rom
```

Now I run df to look at my drives (excluding the cdrom):

```
sudo df -T -h /dev/sd*
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  912M     0  912M   0% /dev
/dev/sda1      xfs       497M  186M  311M  38% /boot
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  912M     0  912M   0% /dev
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  912M     0  912M   0% /dev
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  912M     0  912M   0% /dev
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  912M     0  912M   0% /dev
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  912M     0  912M   0% /dev
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  912M     0  912M   0% /dev
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  912M     0  912M   0% /dev
```

I'm super confused about what df is showing me here.

Why are their so many devtmpfs entries and why are they all the same size?

Running df on every partition (except /dev/sda1) shows devtmpfs with a size of 912M

Comment: Obviously there is only one udev /devtmpfs. run it without /dev/sd*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have at least that many sd* entries in /dev.

Try checking it with something like:

`for devsd in $(ls -1 /dev/sd*); do echo " \n This is for:  $devsd" && df -Th $devsd; done`

You'll likely have a devtmpfs listed for each one. If you want to get a better idea of what your hard disks are really doing, just leave off the path at the end.

`df -Th`

Answer (score 0):

I actually am unsure of the devtmpfs entries.  However, the lsblk command shows you the major hard drive followed by partitions. So sdb1 - 4 are partitions on the hard drive mounted as  sdb. HTH